# Nginx how to block direct access to file

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm a beginner in nginx and I can't find a solution to restrict direct access to file, but only direct access.

To make myself clear : I have a web page which contains a video. I can read it directly by clicking on it, but when I do right click on the video and open it on a new tab, I want to get a  `403 error` (I don't want user to see path on the URL).

Sadly, I tried to do it with `nginx referer module` by restricting access to the folder containning videos, but it blocks the reading of videos everywhere.

Is someone have a solution please ?
Regards